# Protractor - To log a value from field in Console in protractor

Tags: protractor

I am trying to enter a value through sendkeys method to an email field and I am trying to print it out in console using getAttribute('value') but it is always printing out the whole methoda available for the element instead of just printing out the value of the email field. Is there any other way I can achieve this ?

```
var email = element(by.xpath("//input[@name='email']"));
email.sendKeys('vija' + Date.now() + '@test.com');
console.log(email.getAttribute('value'));

and the output is 
{ parentElementArrayFinder:
   { getWebElements: [Function],
     actionResults_:
      { then: [Function: then],
        cancel: [Function: cancel],
        isPending: [Function: isPending] },
     locator_: { using: 'xpath', value: '//input[@name=\'email\']' },
     click: [Function],
     sendKeys: [Function],
     getTagName: [Function],
     getCssValue: [Function],
     getAttribute: [Function],
     getText: [Function],
     getSize: [Function],
     getLocation: [Function],
```

Comment: While if I try from elementexplorer it prints out the email value. May be I am doing some silly thing here, please help !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to resolve the promise to get the value:

```
var email = element(by.xpath("//input[@name='email']"));
email.sendKeys('vija' + Date.now() + '@test.com');
email.getAttribute('value').then(function(inputValue) {
  console.log(inputValue);
});
```